# Transfer blob betwean two Oracle Apex page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

On first oracle apex page (page_1) i have File Browse control and Storage Type (apex_application_temp_files).

Is it possible blob_content save in application data and use on other page (page_2).

On second page I have Processes and need insert this blob in database.

Comment: Why aren't you saving it on Page 1? Or, if it has to be Page 2, why do you browse for it on Page 1? I mean - why making things complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use APEX_COLLECTION to store the Blob

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm